# How do I merge my branchB of branchA into Master in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, feature-branch

I effectively have this:

```
a -- b -- c                           <-- Master
           \
            d -- e                    <-- BranchA
                  \
                   f -- g -- H -- i   <-- BranchB
```

What I want is to integrate my changes from BranchA and BranchB into Master. I normally like to rebase, but I don't think it's a good idea as my changes are in public repos, and in particular, **commit H is someone else's work.**

So if I am right in my assumption that a merge is easier, I am wondering, do I need to merge Master into BranchA, then merge BranchA into BranchB, before merging BranchB back into Master, or can I save some time and *just* merge Master into BranchB, then merge it all back in? I understand this will leave a messy commit history, hence my previous paragraph.

### Edit:

There are changes in the master as this is a team project.

Comment: If there are additional commits in `master` past commit `c`, it would be helpful to include them in the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check out the `master` and merge `BranchB` into it, this merges all changes into master as `BranchB` contains all changes from `BranchA`.

```
a -- b -- c                           
           \
            d -- e                    <-- BranchA
                  \
                   f -- g -- H -- i   <-- Master, BranchB
```

Since this will lead to a fast forward merge, if there are no changes on the `master`, you might want to consider the option `--no-ff` that creates a new commit telling explicitly that the branch hand been merged.

```
a -- b -- c -------------------------- j  <-- Master
           \                          /
            d -- e                   /  <-- BranchA
                  \                 /
                   f -- g -- H -- i   <-- BranchB
```

Depending on what you want to "tell" with the history, you can also merge first merge `BranchA` first and then `BranchB`.

```
a -- b -- c -------j------------------ k  <-- Master
           \      /                   /
            d -- e                   /  <-- BranchA
                  \                 /
                   f -- g -- H -- i   <-- BranchB
```

in all three cases, the resulting code of the merge is the same, just the history is different.

Comment: See my edit, there are changes on the master. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: In that case only the last two options are possible. still i would always use the `-no-ff` option, and additionally merge the brances as often as possible, so if feature A is finished, merge it into master. When that happened, you can rebase the branch B onto that result. It is not a good practice when multple persons work in the same branch, consider everyone working on their own branch, which makes also the merges (and potential conflicts) smaller

Answer (score 0):

This mostly depends on your workflow between and the other maintainers.

To achieve your goal, yes, you can simply merge branches A and B into master one after the other.

Unless... you are following some form of [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) where your `BranchA` is your release branch and you need it to merge both into `master` and `BranchB`, but given your diagram and question, I am assuming that's not the exact convention you are following.